# Set color of one UIBarButtonItem using IBOutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I can't seem to find this anywhere on stack because every solution just mentions how you can set your custom appearance through `AppDelegate` or through setting the *appearance*.

All I need is to set ONE and only this one `UIBarButtonItem` to a custom hexColor using a method called `colorWithHexString:` that comes from a class extension(added to the project).

my property:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *grNextButton;
```

what I'm trying to use in my .m file:

```
grNextButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#669900"];
```

What is the code that I need to successfully change `grNextButton`?

Comment: @Chizx What is wrong with using `tintColor`. What is the behavior you are seeing? Also, what is the content of this button? Is it text, an image, or a custom view?

Comment: The button is just a `UIBarButtonItem` that has been added to the top navigation bar appropriately at the upper right hand corner and I can't seem to set it's tintColor... no change is detected :/

Answer (score 0):

Use `RGBcolor` code like this, hope it will solve your problem.

```
grNextButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f 
                                         green:50/255.0f 
                                          blue:60/255.0f 
                                         alpha:1.0f];
```

The color code I used are example color code you can choose your appropriate  color code from
[here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm)