# Cant set rightBarButtonItem tintColor

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, tintcolor

Im attempting to set only the rightBarButtonItem of my navigationItem's on navigationBar. I'm using this code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

The second line does nothing however and both the left and right `UIBarButtonItem` stay red. What could be causing this issue?

I have also tried:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.rightBarButtonReferenceIBOutlet setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

I have also tried just using this line of code:

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

And the right bar button remains red. I cannot figure out what is causing this issue.

PS.. still no answer [Set color of one UIBarButtonItem using IBOutlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847976/set-color-of-one-uibarbuttonitem-using-iboutlet)
Also seems the same issue is here [UIBarButtonItem setTintColor doesn't work on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131481/uibarbuttonitem-settintcolor-doesnt-work-on-ios7)

Comment: Just tried and worked for me :/

I created a new Xcode project with a master/detail template, put those two lines at the end of the `viewDidLoad` and it worked.

Where did you put those lines?
What is your iOS target (iOS9 for me)

Comment: Navigation bar tint color will influence on all view controllers in navigation.But item only one.

Comment: @QuentinRibierre I put it at the end of the viewDidLoad, it doesn't work for me? is something overriding this?

Comment: Word. Try to put some breakpoint I guess then? To see if it's overridden or not?

Comment: Breakpoint is not going to show me if its overidden, Im not sure where I would check to see if the property is overidden?

Comment: @Chisx : Are you using only the text or any custom image for bar button ? and also the above code works for me in iOS (9.0, 9.1).